# ScrollView with swipe and scroll

Tags: android

I have `ScrollView` with `LinearLayout`. In `LinearLayout` I am adding `WebView` with scrollable content. In `LinearLayout` I have some buttons. I want to implement both functionality vertical scroll and swipe from left to right. Can anybody tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Put a HorizontalScrollView inside your ScrollView?

Answer (score 0):

You should disable scroll of WebView and Webview width/height fit ScrollView width/height.